# Starting Google App Engine Dev Server in junit

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit

I am trying to start the Google App Engine DevServer from within my junit script so that I can gather test coverage statistics for my server side code including the servlet layer.

I have tried using the DevAppServerTestRunner but I get an initialization error without any explanation. Code reproduced below.

```
package uk.me.mukherjee.swindle.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.BaseDevAppServerTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.DevAppServerTest;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.DevAppServerTestRunner;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalURLFetchServiceTestConfig;

@RunWith(DevAppServerTestRunner.class)
@DevAppServerTest(AppTest2.TestConfig.class)

public class AppTest2 {

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper testHelper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalURLFetchServiceTestConfig(),
            new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

    public static class TestConfig extends BaseDevAppServerTestConfig {

        public File getSdkRoot() {
            return new File(
                    "/Users/pmu/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.64/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.64");
        }

        public File getAppDir() {
            return new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/swindle-1.7-SNAPSHOT");
        }

        public List<URL> getClasspath() {
            List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>();
            String classpathStr = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
            String[] classpaths = classpathStr.split(":");
            for (String c : classpaths) {
                File f = new File(c);
                try {
                    urls.add(f.toURL());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }

            return urls;

        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setUpHelper() {
        testHelper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDownHelper() {
        testHelper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Running in maven I get the following error:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.284 sec <<< FAILURE!
initializationError(uk.me.mukherjee.swindle.test.AppTest2)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create a DevAppServer
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:401)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:31)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:318)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:315)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:314)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:266)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.DevAppServerTestHelper.startServer(DevAppServerTestHelper.java:62)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.DevAppServerTestRunner.startServerAndIsolateClass(DevAppServerTestRunner.java:86)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.DevAppServerTestRunner.<init>(DevAppServerTestRunner.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:127)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:386)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevSocketImplFactory.<clinit>(DevSocketImplFactory.java:74)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2348)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2177)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevSocketImplFactory.<clinit>(DevSocketImplFactory.java:72)
        ... 37 more
```

Minimal pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <version>1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <groupId>uk.me.mukherjee.swindle</groupId>
  <artifactId>swindle</artifactId>
  <properties>
    <appengine.version>1.9.64</appengine.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>${appengine.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
      <version>${appengine.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>${appengine.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-agent-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.38</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is there any whatsoever error that you can share with community?

Comment: Hi, apologies I didn't get an error message in Eclipse but running directly in Maven I get an error which I have appended to the original question.

Comment: I am not sure if ` java.lang.ClassCastException: ClassLoader is jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4459eb14, not a URLClassLoader.` has something with your code in `getClasspath()`. Could you try to simplify `getClasspath()` as much as possible and rule out that the error is due to something in it?

Comment: Apologies the original error message I included was incorrect - it was related to the JDK version. I have attached the correct error message.

Comment: Look, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264254) looks quite similar to what you have posted now. Please share your `pom.xml` but delete all sensitive info like you Goocle Cloud Project ID!

Comment: Also, please provide in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, I have just added the smallest pom.xml I could create that still generates the error message.

Comment: Look at these pom.xml entries that are required in the properties section - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven#configuring_java

Comment: Thanks. I added these properties to my pom.xml but I get the identical error message.

Comment: I have performed the a simple unit test by using the files from [this official Google Cloud Platform repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples.git) under `unittest`. [Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/unittests/pom.xml) is a link to the pom.xml file that was used here. Can you try making your one look like that? Try adding missing or different dependencies one by one and trying to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have aligned my pom.xml with this example but the same error persists. Moreover this sample code is just normal junit testing, it does not try to run the DevAppServer inline as part of the junit test.

Comment: I saw this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422546/caused-by-java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-caused-by-java-lang-runtimeexc) that runs into one of your errors, and it's using JUnit but Gradle. Also, I saw this other [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/dKxSlL1sEak) in Google Groups that may be of help.

Comment: Many thanks for this. My problem is slightly different. The root cause is

`Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")`